# Select random column where minimum total values are same

Tags: mysql, sql

I need random column where column values are same. Here d1, d2, d3 column values are same. Least column becomes only the `d1` column not d2 or d3.

```
id  date                    name    d1  d2  d3  d4  least_val   least_col
1   2017-02-10T09:00:00Z    bimal   1   2   3   4   1           d1
2   2017-02-10T09:00:00Z    amal    8   7   4   5   8           d1
3   2017-02-10T09:00:00Z    kamal   9   9   11  12  9           d1
```

```
    select f.*,
       (case ff.least_col
             when 'd1' then d1
             when 'd2' then d2
             when 'd3' then d3
             when 'd4' then d4
        end) as least_val,
        ff.least_col
from formal f cross join
     (select least(sum(d1), sum(d2), sum(d3), sum(d4)) as least_val,
             (case least(sum(d1), sum(d2), sum(d3), sum(d4))
                   when sum(d1) then 'd1'
                   when sum(d2) then 'd2'
                   when sum(d3) then 'd3'
                   when sum(d4) then 'd4'
              end) as least_col
      from formal
     ) ff;
```

[See the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e0fa2/1)

Is it possible to get `least_col` randomly it means least column will be either `d1` or `d2` or `d3` not always `d1`. I want to say, every execution time `least_col` will be changed where values are same?

Comment: You want LEAST of SUM, why do you use random column for `least_val` and `least_col`, that sum will be different from your original LEAST_SUM? And what is the meaning of `least_val` and `least_col` you want for each row?

Comment: `least_val` means least value and `least_col` means least column. Here sum(d1), sum(d2), sum(d3) column values are same i.e. 18. Always least column shows `d1` column and values. I need to set any column from  sum(d1), sum(d2), sum(d3) which will be set randomly not always `d1` column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer, Hope this helps you:

```
select *,Case When d1 < d2 And d1 < d3 And d1<d4 Then d1
            When d2 < d1 And d2 < d3 And d2<d4 Then d2
            When d3 < d1 And d3 < d2 And d3<d4 Then d3
            Else d4 end Least_Value
         ,Case When d1 < d2 And d1 < d3 And d1<d4 Then 'd1'
            When d2 < d1 And d2 < d3 And d2<d4 Then 'd2'
            When d3 < d1 And d3 < d2 And d3<d4 Then 'd3'
            Else 'd4' end Least_Column
from formal
```

Check the answer in:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e0fa2/9)

Comment: I need least value from sum(d1), sum(d2), sum(d3), sum(d4) which will be set randomly, as here sum value of d1,  d2, d3 are same. plz check my fiddle.